# Is it required to check 16 byte memory alignment when create a Mat of opencv?

Tags: opencv, intel-ipp

I remember when using intel ipp, the width of image has to be aligned with 16 byte boundary. which means if width % 16 != 0, need fill a few bytes at the end of each row.

Does opencv has this kind of requirement?

Comment: It is not a requirement. There are cases when the execution time is going to be longer when `width % 16 != 0`, but OpenCV handles it quietly without any warnings. OpenCV supports creating a `Mat` with desired bytes stride/step (added padding). I never saw a functions with documented stride (step) alignment recommendation.